# High CPU usage when reading /dev/gpiomem

Tags: go, cpu, raspberry-pi4

Is there something in my Golang code that would be causing high cpu usage?

The code should read a button on the GPIO pin on a Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB) and when pressed send an REST post message to another program.

I tried using more sleep and no sleep, ive tried changing the code to use a falling edge detection method on the pin. Nothing has changed the high CPU usage.

[image]

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/stianeikeland/go-rpio"
    "os"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Starting Stream Control 0.1")

    pinOpenError := rpio.Open()

    if pinOpenError != nil {
        fmt.Println("Pin Open Error: ", pinOpenError.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    pin := rpio.Pin(18)
    pin.Input()
    pin.PullUp()

    var PID string
    start := time.Now()

    StreamRunning := false;

    fmt.Println("Reading and Controlling")
    for {
        res := pin.Read()
        if res == 0 {
            if StreamRunning == false  && time.Since(start).Seconds() > 10{
            
            var StartStreamError error
            PID, StartStreamError = StartStream()
            if StartStreamError != nil {
                fmt.Println("Start Stream Error: ", StartStreamError.Error())
            }
            fmt.Println("PID = " + PID)

            start = time.Now()
            StreamRunning = true;

            } else {
                if time.Since(start).Seconds() > 10 {
                    StopStream(PID)
                    StreamRunning = false;
                    start = time.Now()
                } 
            }
        }
    
        time.Sleep(100)
    }
}

func postHTTP(url string, requestString string) ([]byte, error){

    var blankBody []byte 

    payload := strings.NewReader(requestString)

    client := &http.Client{}
    req, clientError := http.NewRequest("POST", url, payload)
    if clientError != nil {
        return blankBody, clientError 
    }
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    res, requestError := client.Do(req)
    if requestError != nil {
        return blankBody, requestError
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()
    returnBody, returnError := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    return returnBody, returnError
}

func StartStream()(string, error) {
    fmt.Println("Start Stream")
    response, StreamOnError := postHTTP("http://localhost:3000/startStream","{\"devicePath\":\"/dev/video0\",\"streamName\":\"LumiPi-003\"}")
    if StreamOnError != nil {
        fmt.Println("Stream On Error: ", StreamOnError.Error())
        return "0", StreamOnError
    }
    splitstrings := strings.Split(string(response),",")
    for i := range splitstrings {
        if strings.Contains(splitstrings[i], "\"pid\":") {
        linesplit := strings.Split(splitstrings[i],":")
        return linesplit[1], nil
        }
    }
    return "0", nil
}

func StopStream(PID string)(error) {
    fmt.Println("Stop Stream")
    command := "{\"pid\":" + PID +  "}"
    _, StreamOnError := postHTTP("http://localhost:3000/stopStream",command)
    if StreamOnError != nil {
        fmt.Println("Stream Off Error: ", StreamOnError.Error())
        return StreamOnError
    }
    return nil 
}
```

Picture below shows the affect time.sleep has on the program.

[image]

Comment: What is `sleep(100)`? Is that `time.Sleep`? If so, you are sleeping 100 nsecs, which isn't much.

Comment: Sorry, Yes that was time.Sleep(), I have edited the code. It looks thou like Time.Sleep is now causing the whole Pi to crash. 

Without the Time.Sleep() the cpu usage is high but the PI does not randomly crash after pushing the button, but it does with time.sleep() set to any value.

Comment: Define "crash". Does it panic? Is there a stack?

Comment: I'll add a picture because the remote terminals all instantly stop and only plugging in a screen shows the issue when it crashes.

Comment: There are several things displayed during the crash/panic but it scrolls so fast to actually see any of it.

Comment: The screenshot is warning message from journald. It is complaining that it cannot write diag messages because your filesystem is not writeable. This may or may not be related to your program.

Comment: It only happens with time.Sleep(), remove time.Sleep() and the program runs happly for hours with no crashes but still uses high CPU issues. 

I think time.Sleep is causing the Pi to hold open /dev/gpiomem so the next read/write causes the crash. 

That issue aside of crashing... what in the program without time.Sleep() would cause high cpu usage?

Comment: Well, if the reason is really «hold open /dev/gpiomem», just move the Open and Close operation inside the `for` loop so they are done on each iteration: open→read→close→repeat if needed, _but first sleep for some time._

Comment: Think we have a winner, Thanks Kostix, i was just following all the examples in the library repo that opened the memory file outside the loop. 

So I open, setup pin requirements, read, close and now sleep for a longer period of time 100*time.Millisecond and it seems to work well now

Answer (score 0):

The time.Sleep() function was causing the PI to crash when rpio.Open() was still open.

Opening, reading the pins and closing allowed time.Sleep() to be used with a much larger delay which in turn dropped the cpu usage because its not constantly looping.

[image]

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/stianeikeland/go-rpio"
    "os"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Starting Stream Control 0.1")

    var PID string
    start := time.Now()

    StreamRunning := false;

    fmt.Println("Reading and Controlling")
    for {

        pinOpenError := rpio.Open()
        if pinOpenError != nil {
            fmt.Println("Pin Open Error: ", pinOpenError.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        pin := rpio.Pin(18)
        pin.Input()
        pin.PullUp()
        res := pin.Read()
        rpio.Close()
        if res == 0 {
            if StreamRunning == false  && time.Since(start).Seconds() > 10{
            
            var StartStreamError error
            PID, StartStreamError = StartStream()
            if StartStreamError != nil {
                fmt.Println("Start Stream Error: ", StartStreamError.Error())
            }
            fmt.Println("PID = " + PID)

            start = time.Now()
            StreamRunning = true;

            } else {
                if time.Since(start).Seconds() > 10 {
                    StopStream(PID)
                    StreamRunning = false;
                    start = time.Now()
                } 
            }
        }

    time.Sleep(100*time.Millisecond)

    }
}

func postHTTP(url string, requestString string) ([]byte, error){

    var blankBody []byte 

    payload := strings.NewReader(requestString)

    client := &http.Client{}
    req, clientError := http.NewRequest("POST", url, payload)
    if clientError != nil {
        return blankBody, clientError 
    }
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    res, requestError := client.Do(req)
    if requestError != nil {
        return blankBody, requestError
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()
    returnBody, returnError := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    return returnBody, returnError
}

func StartStream()(string, error) {
    fmt.Println("Start Stream")
    response, StreamOnError := postHTTP("http://localhost:3000/startStream","{\"devicePath\":\"/dev/video0\",\"streamName\":\"LumiPi-003\"}")
    if StreamOnError != nil {
        fmt.Println("Stream On Error: ", StreamOnError.Error())
        return "0", StreamOnError
    }
    splitstrings := strings.Split(string(response),",")
    for i := range splitstrings {
        if strings.Contains(splitstrings[i], "\"pid\":") {
        linesplit := strings.Split(splitstrings[i],":")
        return linesplit[1], nil
        }
    }
    return "0", nil
}

func StopStream(PID string)(error) {
    fmt.Println("Stop Stream")
    command := "{\"pid\":" + PID +  "}"
    _, StreamOnError := postHTTP("http://localhost:3000/stopStream",command)
    if StreamOnError != nil {
        fmt.Println("Stream Off Error: ", StreamOnError.Error())
        return StreamOnError
    }
    return nil 
}
```